# Can I use spinner style from an other sdk, without changing compile version?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am using android compile version 2.2 in my app, because of programming problems with newer. But the spinner style in this version is very ugly. So can I use the style from an other sdk version, without changing the compile version?

Comment: What kind of compilation errors do you get when you change the compile version?

Comment: the errors are not the problem, i want to load a https site with authentification request in my webview and I got this only working in froyo.

Comment: how do you load the page?

Answer (score 0):

No. But, you can change the spinner background with drawable.Like:

```
<Spinnner android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:background="@drawable/new_one"/>
```

Comment: yes i have done that, but i want to change the design of the menu when you have clicked the spinner. How can I do that?

Comment: Means do u want to change the dialog that comes whenever we click on spinner.

Comment: If u are using ArrayAdapter, use customLayout in adapter.setDropDownViewResource("custom layout"). If u are using customAdapter then override getDropDownView() and inflate ur custom layout

Comment: do you know how to disable the darkening of the back?

Comment: In your AppTheme style declare <item android:backgroundDimEnabled>false</item>